# Hibernate call sql server stored procedure throws Incorrect syntax near '@P0'

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures

the sql server stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectStaff @rankabbr varchar(14), @sex varchar(1)
AS
SELECT * FROM staff WHERE rankabbr = @rankabbr AND sex = @sex
```

and I can successfully run it in SSMS by

```
exec SelectStaff  'AEO', 'M';
```

but in eclipse, I use hibernate to call this stored procedure as follow:

```
Session session2 = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
org.hibernate.Query query = session2.createSQLQuery(" call SelectStaff(:rankabbr, :sex) ")                    
          .setParameter("rankabbr","AEO")
          .setParameter("sex", "M");
List<Object[]> results =query.list();
```

but error return as follow:

> 23:30:57,708 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]
>   (default task-7) SQL Error: 102, SQLState: S0001 23:30:57,741 ERROR
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-7)
>   Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.

what is the reason?
I have tried to add { } in the call as

```
org.hibernate.Query query = session2.createSQLQuery("{ call SelectStaff(:rankabbr, :sex) }")                      
                      .setParameter("rankabbr","AEO")
                      .setParameter("sex", "M");
```

but the error is the same.

I try to replace SQLServerDialect with SQLServer2012Dialect but the same error.

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: hibernate core 5.0.6

Answer (score 0):

I find the following code is work:

```
Session session2 = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
ProcedureCall call = session2.createStoredProcedureCall("SelectStaff");
call.registerParameter( 1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue("AEO");
call.registerParameter( 2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue("M");
Output output = call.getOutputs().getCurrent();
List<Object[]> results;
if (output.isResultSet()) {
     results = ( (ResultSetOutput) output ).getResultList();
     for (Object[] row:results) {
         // ......
     }
}
```